# Removing member-ness of function signature type? (operator() of lambda)

Tags: c++, lambda, type-erasure, member-functions

I would like to be able to instantiate a `std::function` with the name alone of an encapsulated lambda instead of with a hardcoded signature:

```
#include <functional>

auto l = [](bool b){ return b ? 1 : 0; };
std::function<int(bool)> f(l);            // XXX - don't want the type hardcoded

// Is something like this possible?
// using sig_t = strip_memberness<decltype(l::operator())>;
// std::function<sig_t> f(l);
```

Is there any way to yield, for the `std::function<>` parameter, the type `int(bool)` from `l`?

Even if C++17-style template parameter deduction might make this particular use case possible in the future, I am unfortunately limited to GCC 6/C++14 and would also like access to the type for purposes other than template instantiation.

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to write a type trait that converts `R (T::*)(Args...)` to `R(Args...)`. Note that `l::operator()` is not valid syntax. `&decltype(l)::operator()` might work though.

Comment: I'm not sure if creating a `std::function` object without knowing the type of the actual function object makes much sense. How would you use the `std::function` object? What is the reason behind not wanting to  provide the function type? What is the actual problem you want to solve by this? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: The example is a gross oversimplification of something I have buried in a templated type erasure utility class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct MemberToFunction;

template <typename R, typename T, typename ... Args>
struct MemberToFunction<R (T::*)(Args...)> {
    using type = R(Args...);
};

template <typename R, typename T, typename ... Args>
struct MemberToFunction<R (T::*)(Args...) const> {
    using type = R(Args...);
};

int main()
{
    auto l = [](bool b){ return b ? 1 : 0; };
    std::function<MemberToFunction<decltype(&decltype(l)::operator())>::type> f(l);
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PPMT34764)